# Check if table exists in azure storage powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

i have this powershell using which I want to create new table in azure storage account.

```
Param(
 [string]$rgName,
 [string] $tableName
 )
 $storcontext= New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString '$(MyConnectionString)'

if(!(Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storcontext ))
 {
   New-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storcontext
 }
```

New-AzureStorageTable command works perfect.however i tried adding a check to see if table already exists . but on Get command, powershell throws me saying table does not exist.

What I want to do is check if table exist, if not , then create it.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: How to check if an column is exist in a table  or not in powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cmdlet throws an error if the table doesn't exists so you could set the ErrorAction to SilentlyContinue and specify a variable for the error which you could check:

```
Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storcontext -ErrorVariable ev -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($ev) {
New-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storcontext
}
```